# How do I print content of reference in JAVA?

Tags: java, string, sorting, reference

Newbie question comming up. Trying to get my head around JAVA.

How do I print out the content of the reference and not just their postition ? My program is ment to get some text in from the user, and print it out in a reverse order.

Here is my program (so far):

```
package myProgram;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class someRandomClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write som text here");
    StringBuilder outPut = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = word.length()-1; i>=0; i--){
        outPut.append(i);
    }
    System.out.println(outPut.toString());
  }
}
```

I am greatfull for any help and tips! :)

Comment: ...ok? What do you call it then?

Comment: it is called "reference" and is different from pointers. if you want to understand java, make sure you understand reference in java.

Comment: You don't have to reinvent the wheel - you're already using StringBuilder so just use its [reverse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse()) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
 outPut.append(i);
```

you are appending the value of your loop counter. You surely mean

```
 outPut.append(word.charAt(i));
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to appending the integers instead of the appropriate characters. Try this instead:

`outPut.append(word.substring(i, i + 1))`

This way, the individual characters of `word` are appended to your `StringBuilder`. Note that the `append` method could also take a `char` as an argument, so you are also able to use `word.charAt(i)`.

Comment: Never use `substring(i, i + 1)` in place of `charAt(i)`.

Comment: One returns a string, the other a character. Of course you could always do ("" + s.charAt(..)) but, regardless, what is the disadvantage of the substring method? Admittedly, it will be slower than charAt but in this case it shouldn't make a large difference.

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to emit the character at the position? Try using [`String.charAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29).

```
outPut.append(word.charAt(i));
```

I'd probably avoid that and just index the `char[]` from [`String.toCharArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29), though.

To be honest, I'd avoid doing the reversal loop manually to begin with... try something as follows:

```
final String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter text below");
System.out.println(new StringBuilder(word).reverse());
```

[`StringBuilder.reverse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse%28%29) should do the work for you (likely in a more efficient way, too). You also don't need to call `toString` manually, as `println` will do that for you.